# Is there Java CAPS equivalent from .NET

Tags: .net, web-services, frameworks

I am looking for an integration framework for building and managing SOA composite applications consist of exposing web services, calling 3rd party web services, performing business logic and invoking database.

It is similar to Sun Java Composite Application Platform Suite (Java CAPS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you may be looking for BizTalk from Microsoft.

However, depending on how heavy-duty your needs are, you may find that they are served by the basics of WCF (the Microsoft platform for developing web services and clients for them), plus the features of Windows Workflow Foundation (WF). One can easily use WF to create programs that consume one or more web services. You can also expose a WF workflow as a service itself.

Where the composite application is focused on a process like an ETL, you can do a lot with SQL Server Integration Services, which can consume web services as part of an overall ETL task.

See the [WCF Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/wcf/) and the [WF Developer Centers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/wf/) on MSDN .

Comment: Thanks BizTalk may be a bit overkill in this case. I agree with WCF and WF and they are my first consideration, I am look for an application framework built on top of those specifically for SOA architecture.

Comment: BizTalk is really something similar to what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with CAPS but it sounds very similar to Microsoft's Enterprise Library http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203099.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but not quiet, I am looking for a SOA integration framework from .NET.